# How do I open a port on one IP only with UFW?

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I have seven IPs on my server. Using UFW, if I enter the rule 'ufw allow 7443', port 7443 is exposed and opened on all my IPs. But I only want port 7443 to be exposed on one particular IP address and to be closed on all the others. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the destination IP address as the `to` address:

```
sudo ufw allow to 198.51.100.205 port 7443/tcp
```

Comment: Specifying the protocol with the proto argument worked for me:
`sudo ufw allow to 198.51.100.205 port 7443 proto tcp`